# I've a .pfx file and can't be able to use it

Tags: ssl, iis-8, pfx

My website is running on IIS 8 and has a websitepanel as control panel. But there I cant find nothing related to SSL or anything like that. Now how can I use this certificate for my site.

[Here is the screenshot of the panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEx8e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.pfx file is for SSL. You can refer below URL to export and import SSL in windows.

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/1245/How-to-export-an-SSL-certificate-from-Windows-server.html

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/1246/How-to-import-SSL-certificate-in-Windows-server.html

You need to import .pfx file in IIS and it cannot be done from website panel.
Hope this helps.